# Get the average of two multiplied columns in one cell, without an extra column

Tags: google-sheets

So I've been searching and experimenting with formulas I've found across the internet that are supposed to to what I need but definitely do not.

What I need is the average of the 'total' column in this, which would be 13, without actually having to have a 'total' column. In my head the formula would be something like, `=AVERAGE(A1*B1,A2*B2,A3*B3)` 
but without having to manually enter each set of cells.

[image: spreadsheet example]

Instead what seems to be happening when I use the formulas I've found, is that it multiplies the total sums of each column, and then averages that, which results in 39.

[image: wrong result example]

I know a simple solution would be to just leave that 'total' column there, and then just average that, but I don't want to add an unnecessary column when it seems like there should be a way to multiply each set of cells and then sum that and get the average of those in one formula.

Formulas I've tried so far:

```
=AVERAGE(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A,B1:B))  <---results in 39

=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(A1:A*B1:B))  <---results in 39.75

=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A,B1:B)/COUNT(A1:A)  <---results in 39.75

=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(MULTIPLY(A1:A,B1:B),COUNT(A1:A)))     <---results in 10.5???
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A*B1:B))/counta(A1:A)
```

[image]

Comment: Holy shit thank you. I was confused at first about how =SUM was resulting in an average, but then I realized the /count function was outside the main formula. Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: Thanks glad it helped.  If you have a chance can you please "accept" the answer